# android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class, have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml? dart

Tags: android, flutter

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {<project_id>/com.avinash.gotluru.cc_avenue.Framework.WebViewActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Getting this error while integrating ccavenue payment gateway in flutter android app.

```css
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="<app_id>">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
   <application
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
                android:value="flutterpropertyfinderapp"/>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="<api_key>" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <uses-library 
            android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
            android:required="false" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

```html
try {
      await CcAvenue.cCAvenueInit(
          transUrl: 'https://test.ccavenue.com/transaction/initTrans',
          accessCode: '<access_code>',
          amount: '10',
          cancelUrl: 'http://122.182.6.216/merchant/ccavResponseHandler.jsp',
          currencyType: 'INR',
          merchantId: '<merchant_id>',
          orderId: '519',
          redirectUrl: 'http://122.182.6.216/merchant/ccavResponseHandler.jsp',
          rsaKeyUrl: 'https://test.ccavenue.com/transaction/jsp/GetRSA.jsp');
    } catch (e) {
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Something Went Wrong!");
    }
```

I have no idea about this bug.

Comment: You have  to declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml


<activity android:name="com.avinash.gotluru.cc_avenue.Framework.WebViewActivity" />

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: did you get solution for this